# How to completely disable the link button?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling LinkButton doesn't disable the click event in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754497/disabling-linkbutton-doesnt-disable-the-click-event-in-javascript)

I have a linkbutton in ASP.NET.

I have set its property  Enabled = false;

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" runat="server" 
                Enabled = "false" 
                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure ?')" > Click Me
                        </asp:LinkButton>
```

Event thought I have set the property `Enabled = false` the `OnClientClick` event is still fired.

How can I prevent the `OnClientClick` event from firing?

Comment: hello this may help you http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2009/10/03/disabling-linkbutton-hyperlink-and-imagebutton-completely.aspx and this http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2009/05/how-to-enable-or-disable-linkbutton-in.html

Comment: @PresleyDias: Then post it as an answer so that Rajbir can accept it. Or delete this question Rajbir.

Comment: I had the same problem and I was using CssClass. I changed it to class it worked. the Enabled property is working also I have to put OnClientClick='<%# !Item.Application.ApplicationClosed ? "return ShowConfirmEvaluationDelete(this.id);" : "" %>'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is from [Disables the link button](http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2009/10/03/disabling-linkbutton-hyperlink-and-imagebutton-completely.aspx)

```
/// <summary>
/// Disables the link button.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="linkButton">The LinkButton to be disabled.</param>
public static void DisableLinkButton(LinkButton linkButton)
{
    linkButton.Attributes.Remove("href");
    linkButton.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color] = "gray";
    linkButton.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor] = "default";
    if (linkButton.Enabled != false)
    {
       linkButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    if (linkButton.OnClientClick != null)
    {
        linkButton.OnClientClick = null;
    }
}
```

check this also [how-to-enable-or-disable-linkbutton](http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2009/05/how-to-enable-or-disable-linkbutton-in.html)

Answer (score -8):

**In Page Load you can write following way:**

```
page_load
{    
   if(lnkButton.Enabled)
      lnkButton.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick","Javascript");    
}
```