# Disable linkbutton in Wizard Control created programmatically

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, wizard, sidebar, linkbutton

I need your help. I try unsuccessfully to disable linkbutton in my Wizard control.

I cannot use javascript and I must use a userControl.

I do not want this functionnality because if I am in step 4 and I click on link for step 1, my data does not persist (each wizardStep contains a different UserControl). If you think you can resolve this problem, I do not need to resolve linkbutton problem.

I think my problem is due to the wizard because I try this : 
[Disable linkbutton programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682833/how-to-completely-disable-the-link-button)
and it still not works :(

linkbutton.commandName = null seems to work. I can click but it does not change the current wizardStep.

This is my code :

```
public class EditOrNew : UserControl
{
    Wizard w = new Wizard();
    WizardStep ws1 = new WizardStep();
    WizardStep ws2 = new WizardStep();
    WizardStep ws3 = new WizardStep();
    WizardStep ws4 = new WizardStep();

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        w.ID = "w";                 
        ws1.ID = "ws1";
        ws2.ID = "ws2";
        ws3.ID = "ws3";
        ws4.ID = "ws4";
        ws1.Title = "Select a client";            
        ws1.StepType = WizardStepType.Start;
        ws2.Title = "Select a project";
        ws3.Title = "Select a bot type";
        ws4.Title = "Configure the new task";
        ws4.StepType = WizardStepType.Finish;
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(w);
        // Allow access to buttonlink in the wizard
        Control ctrl = w.FindControl("SideBarContainer");
        DataList dl = (DataList)ctrl.FindControl("SideBarList");
        foreach (DataListItem item in dl.Items)
        {
            LinkButton b = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("SideBarButton"); 
            b.CommandName = null;  
            // NOT WORK      
            //b.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled"); 
            //b.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;                               
            //b.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor] = "default";
            //b.Enabled = false;
            //b.OnClientClick = null;
            //b.Attributes.Remove("href");
            //b.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color] = "gray";                
        }
     }
```

I try to put the allow access code to different place.

I do not understand why commandName is OK while the rest is not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wizard steps are binded into the DataList dl, so you can add an handler to dl :

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    w.ID = "w";                 
    ws1.ID = "ws1";
    ws2.ID = "ws2";
    ws3.ID = "ws3";
    ws4.ID = "ws4";
    ws1.Title = "Select a client";            
    ws1.StepType = WizardStepType.Start;
    ws2.Title = "Select a project";
    ws3.Title = "Select a bot type";
    ws4.Title = "Configure the new task";
    ws4.StepType = WizardStepType.Finish;

    DataList dl= (DataList)w.FindControl("SideBarContainer").FindControl("SideBarList");
    dl.ItemDataBound += w_ItemDataBound;
}

void w_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = e.Item.FindControl("SideBarButton") as LinkButton;
    if (lb != null)
    {
        lb.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

This will leave the sidebar visible, with links highlighted to the corresponding step without being clickable. Only the buttons will be available to navigate then.