# Disable only the link part of a ASP.Net LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.Net LinkButton in a Repeater. In some conditions on some rows i'm trying to disable the link of the button so that it acts more like a Label, where other rows will be a link that fires off the ItemCommand event.

What is a good solution for this? I'm trying to avoid having two separate control on the page to handle pretty much the same thing.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Apologies - question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Wire into the ItemDataBound event for the repeater. In each item, find the link button, and then use a method like on this solution to disable the link button on an item by item basis

[How to completely disable the link button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682833/how-to-completely-disable-the-link-button)