# Disabling the link which is placed in the footer of the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am trying to disable link when a the time is up. Is there anything I miss out? Like in this case I want to disable it when distance = 0.

See the markup below,

```
<FooterTemplate>
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" ValidationGroup="INSERT" OnClick="lnkInsert_Click" runat="server">INSERT</asp:LinkButton>
                                                        <p id="demo"></p>
                                        <script>
                                            // Set the date we're counting down to
                                            var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 11, 2018 20:00:00").getTime();

                                            // Update the count down every 1 second
                                            var x = setInterval(function () {

                                                // Get todays date and time
                                                var now = new Date("Sep 11, 2018 20:00:00").getTime();

                                                // Find the distance between now and the count down date
                                                var distance = countDownDate - now;

                                                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                                                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                                                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                                                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                                                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                                                // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
                                                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                                                    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                                                // If the count down is over, write some text 
                                                if (distance <= 0) {
                                                    clearInterval(x);
                                                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                                                    document.getElementById("lnkInsert").disabled = true;
                                                }
                                            }, 1000);
                                        </script>
                                                    </FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Are both your `countdowndate` and `now` variables actually hardcoded to the same values? Is your problem only that the linkbutton does not get disabled, or is nothing in your script working?

Comment: @AsheraH, Yes they are. I want to test if the disabling works right after I run it. What is wrong with that to deserve a FLAG?

Comment: I did not flag. As the existing answers have suggested, probably something wrong with your selector, I tried this in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdeGwe) with a regular button instead of an asp linkbutton and works fine.

Comment: Check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296651/how-to-disable-linkbutton-with-javascript) for disabling the linkbutton, because i'm not sure your `disabled = true` will work correctly.

Comment: This make me wonder now, Is my IDE not fine perhaps? Do I need to config it somehow maybe?

Comment: What do you think would be wrong with your IDE?

Comment: Putting a simple linkbutton with your script (without the gridview/footertemplate complications) in a web form gives me an error when I run it in a browser: _Error: Can not set the disabled property of an undefined reference or a reference to an empty value._ Definitely seems something is wrong with your selector.

Comment: Okay, so, a LinkButton when you actually run it gets translated into a `<a>` tag in html, which does not have a disabled property the way you might know it. Try looking for suggestions on how to disable a link from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link won't be named `lnkInsert` because ASP.NET will create a unique if for it. 
I would add some class and select the link using that class.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" ClassName="js-insert-link" ValidationGroup="INSERT" OnClick="lnkInsert_Click" runat="server">INSERT</asp:LinkButton>
```

And then:

```
document.querySelector(".js-insert-link").disabled = true;
```

Comment: this still does not make change, i see your logic but still never worked. Is there anything that I missed out?

Comment: Instead of setting the disable could you set the innerText to check if at least is getting the element?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using class you can also set `ClientIDMode` to `Static` which will make id of your link static to `lnkInsert` instead of `somthing_lnkInsert`.

Here is the exact code for your linkbutton which you can use

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" ValidationGroup="INSERT" OnClick="lnkInsert_Click" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">INSERT</asp:LinkButton>
```

and you can use this solution only because you are doing this in footer template not in item template.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get id on client side you can use control.ClientId property inside of *<% %>*

```
<script>
    var lnkInsertId = '<% lnkInsert.ClientID %>';
    document.getElementById(lnkInsertId ).disabled = true; 
</script>
```