# Can't disable LinkButton controll from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have one linkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="_addToCartButton" runat="server" CssClass="button" 
    OnClick="AddToCartClick" OnClientClick="Disable();" ValidationGroup="AddToCartRetail">
        <span>Add To Cart</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

and my javascript

```
function Disable() {
    document.getElementById("_addToCartButton").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

pls help me disable this linkbutton

Comment: I have find a solution you can try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9683378/4706055

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling LinkButton doesn't disable the click event in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754497/disabling-linkbutton-doesnt-disable-the-click-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you want to disabled link button only while processing?

Comment: i disabled link button when i click in AddToCartButton

Answer (score 0):

write your link button as:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnk" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return test(this);"
    OnClick="lnk_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and write java script as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function test(obj) {
        obj.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```